# zurb foundation 4.0 custom Button color without SASS

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html

From the doc it is possible to get Custom Color using Mixin.  I don't know much about SCSS and trying to get by without using it.

I want Black color buttons instead of the default Blue.  It is possible to create some CSS class `.black { ... }` which will make the button black?

Comment: please can you make a fiddle

Comment: Try this: .button.black { background-color: #000000; } then add the class 'black' to your element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your error might be that it is being overridden and one of the only ways of doing it even though it is frowned upon is to use `!important` so you would need to use:

```
.black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Also as you have used !important just for the regular one you also need to add it to your hover method so like this:

```
.black:hover {
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

**Edit**

Just found out that you don't even need important though if it starts to misbehave then that is what to do

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/p868s/

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can override the css by your own class if you do not know SCSS, though it is recommended to change the SCSS variable value in _variables.scss.

The way for css override is:

create a new css file for example. mystyle.css

And then call the css in the html head after

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Foundation 4</title>

  <!-- If you are using CSS version, only link these 2 files, you may add app.css to use for your overrides if you like. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">

  <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<a href="#" class="small button black">.small black colour button</a>
<body>
```

Then your css will override the foundation.css class.

add your css class into the button element in html file.

Please see in the above code.